# Is Django recognizing my mock object?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm really struggling with testing and mock objects.  I am writing the tests on code that I know works--all I'm trying to do is basic tests to make sure I get a response.status_code of 200, but I'm getting a 404.

url.py

```
url(r'^(?P<model_name>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
    crud_views.connect_detail_view, name='detail'),
```

tests.py

```
class SimplePageLoadsTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user('admin', 'admin@dowjones.com', 'admin')
        self.client.login(username='admin', password='admin')
        mock_application = mock.Mock(spec=Application, pk=1)

    def test_detail_application_view(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('detail', kwargs={'model_name': 'application', 'pk':1}))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I'm getting `AssertionError: 404 != 200`, which is not too helpful in terms of debugging (any points on improving that?)

I noticed with pdb that if I put a breakpoint in setUp, I could access the Mock objects, but not if I put the breakpoint in the test itself.  I experimented with defining mock_application in the test; I could access it then, but still got the 404.

Comment: I think `mock_application` is going to be local to just `setUp`, no?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, I moved it into the appropriate test and still got a 404.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you give some more context in your code, I don't see how `mock_application` is being used in your code. I'm not 100% certain, but I don't think that the `mock` module will change the already-existing `Application` object, so you'll need to use the `mock_application` in some manner instead.

Comment: It's really not being used, except for the fact that the URL requires an existing PK of an object

Comment: A fully-formed URL would be something like /application/1/

Comment: So, while you have given your `mock_application` an attribute called `pk` and assigned its value to `1`, that doesn't mean it's in your database, so there's no reason why django would grab it from some models' `objects`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, the view requires an existing PK. Presumably inside that view there is something like:

```
application = get_object_or_404(Application, pk=1)
```

But the thing is, as the comments say, your Mock object is local to the test code itself. Even if you move it into the specific test method, it still won't affect that get_object_or_404 call within the method.

The way to deal with things like this in Django unit tests is simply to create (and save) a model instance in the `setUp` method. Django creates a separate database for the tests, and destroys it at the end of the test, so this is perfectly safe (even if it does stretch the definition of "unit" tests to be relying on the database adapter).

Comment: Ah.  I thought the point of a Mock object was to avoid going through the process of setting up an entire database object (mine have many required attributes and I'm lazy).  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: (I tried using fixtures, but our database is huge and the few simple tests I ran took a very long time)

Comment: A mock object would be useful in that way if you were testing a standalone piece of functionality which accepted an existing model object and did things with it. But your test here is using the test client to call a view, and that view is calling a database query function, so just defining a mock wouldn't work. One thing that could work would be patching the db method itself to return your mock object, but that's probably more work than just creating a real model instance.